# Complex definite integral involving Trigonometric function

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}}dx$$

Try: Put $\tan x=t^2$ and $\sec^2 x dx=2tdt$.

$$I=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{2t}{(1+t^4)\sqrt{1+t}}dt$$

Put $1+t=u^2$ and $dt=2udu$

$$I=\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{4(u^2-1)}{1+(u^2-1)^4}du$$

Could some help me to solve it , Thanks

Comment: I thinks that, after the first change of variable, it could be $t^4$ and not $t^2$.

Comment: The final integrand is a rational fraction. Though tedious, decomposition in simple fractions is doable.